# How to get a specific node in xml according to another node value using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to work with XML like this sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<quizReport version="1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ispring/quizbuilder/quizresults quizReport.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ispring/quizbuilder/quizresults">
<quizSettings timeLimit="0" maxNormalizedScore="100" maxScore="20" quizType="graded">

<passingPercent>0.6</passingPercent>
</quizSettings>
<summary time="4" percent="0.5" score="10">
<variables>
  <variable title="Nom" value="test1411" name="USER_NAME"/>

  <variable title="Courriel" value="" name="USER_EMAIL"/>
</variables>
</summary>


<questions>
<trueFalseQuestion usedAttempts="1" awardedPoints="10" maxAttempts="1" maxPoints="10" status="correct" id="{11AD6662-ACF3-4C2B-A3E6-04311C0DD8DB}">
<direction>Le mot de passe de votre compte iNews est indépendant de votre mot de passe radiocanadien géré par ActiveDirectory. </direction>
<answers userAnswerIndex="0" correctAnswerIndex="0">
<answer>Vrai </answer>
<answer>Faux </answer>
</answers>
</trueFalseQuestion>

<trueFalseQuestion usedAttempts="1" awardedPoints="0" maxAttempts="1" maxPoints="10" status="incorrect" id="{F13CF7F1-C830-41AF-A54C-CE78EE383611}">
<direction>Le protocole FTP permet de reprendre un transfert de fichier qui a été arrêté, sans recommencer le transfert depuis le début. </direction>
<answers userAnswerIndex="1" correctAnswerIndex="0">
<answer>Vrai </answer>
<answer>Faux </answer>
</answers> 
</trueFalseQuestion>
</questions> 
</quizReport>
```

Each question has an ID attribute, e.g. *{11AD6662-ACF3-4C2B-A3E6-04311C0DD8DB}*.
The status of the question is returned as text (i.e. *correct* or *incorrect*).

My goal is to extract each question status and put in a database where a column is labelled with the same question ID (I'm comfortable with MySQL INSERT).

I've tried many solutions (xPath, foreach...) and I can't get any piece of code to work. All my efforts were made with SimpleXMLElement.

So, at the end, I will insert the value *correct* or *incorrect* into the DB under a column labelled with question id (e.g. *{11AD6662-ACF3-4C2B-A3E6-04311C0DD8DB}*) for every single question of the XML (which can contain up to 100 questions). So some sort of loop through the XML is needed.

I must point out that the tag name **truFalseQuestion** may change according to the type of question (another question could be multipleChoiceQuestion for instance). I made this simple XML to help me understand on a step by step basis.

Comment: *under a column labelled {11AD6662-ACF3-4C2B-A3E6-04311C0DD8DB}*...I doubt MySQL allows such a field name. You probably meant another field as *questionid* and this as the value.

Comment: I feel like this approach is going to require that you add more metadata to list the possible question tag names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PHP SimpleXML library](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php) to handle parsing the xml for you. e.g.:

```
//presuming that xml data is stored in $xmlContents
$xmlData = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlContents);
$keys = get_object_vars($xmlData);
$aValues = array();
foreach($keys as $key=>$property) {
    if (stripos($key,'questions')!== false) {       
        foreach($property as $questionType=>$question) {
            $aValues[] = "('".(string)$question['id']."','".(string)$question['status']."')";
        }
    }
}
if (count($aValues)) {
    //presumed table and columns - modify per your names - this is a sample SQL statement - if you are using a different database variant, modify accordingly
    $query = 'INSERT INTO questionStatus (questionId,status) VALUES ' .     implode(',',$aValues);
    print($query);
    //@TODO: run insert statement with your database layer code
}
```

Output with your data:

```
INSERT INTO questionStatus (questionId,status) VALUES ('{11AD6662-ACF3-4C2B-A3E6-04311C0DD8DB}','correct'),('{F13CF7F1-C830-41AF-A54C-CE78EE383611}','incorrect')
```

Comment: How does this solve the different question types problem?

Comment: Indeed, OP mentions *multipleChoiceQuestion* as a potential element among who knows how many else! We should await response from @bassxzero's comment above.

Comment: yeah we can use [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) to find the properties containing 'questions' - hopefully that will suffice?

Comment: Close but... I only get the last node (last question) info.
The way I understand it, the code create an array. So I need to dig into that array, extract the ID with the correct answer... Maybe an "If" code somewhere?
My SQL look like :
Close but... I only get the last node (last question) info.
The way I understand it, the code create an array. So I need to dig into that array, extract the ID with the correct answer... Maybe an "If" code somewhere?
My SQL look like :
`code`$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml (Question01, Question02)  VALUES ('$status_Q1','$status_Q2')";
@bassxzero is right!

Comment: Hmm - I am testing with the data you sent and I see both questions (i.e. id: `11AD6662...`, id: `F13CF7F1...`)

Comment: Kinf of confused now! :)
Code to extract data:
`$xmlData = new SimpleXMLElement($fichierxml);
foreach($xmlData->questions->trueFalseQuestion as $question) {
    $questionID = (string)$question['id'];
    $questionstatus = (string)$question['status'];`
Code to put value in Mysql should be :
`$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml ($questionID) VALUES ('$questionstatus')";` ? This is where I think I'm missing a loop maybe...

Comment: please see my latest revision (or the answer by akrys)

Comment: Right now I'm testing the code in my last comment.
My problem is that the PHP file is fired from an html app, so I can not see "print" function to debug. I need to insert data in the DB to see it. It add an unneccessary level to troubleshoot, but I don't have no choice...
So : I understand the array containt everything, but I can not get it to the DB... Bascially, I just want to insert the `$questionstatus` in the `$questionid` column.
The final goal of this project is to calculate stats about the failure of each question.

Comment: `the PHP file is fired from an html app` - is that asynchronously, e.g. with AJAX? if so, you could run that request in a new tab... or instead of adding print statements, send `console.log` statements to the html app... `insert the $questionstatus in the $questionid` doesn't quite make sense to me but I have updated my answer to hopefully give you an idea ....

Answer (score 0):

You could run through all child nodes of the questions element.

Each child node's tagname can be found using the getName() function.

Here's some sample code. I hope, it can help you to get an idea.

```
<?php
//if your XML is stored in a file named "test.xml", you can load it from there.
//Otherwise try simplexml_load_string($xmlstring)
$file=simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

//get the questions
$questions=$file->questions->children();
foreach($questions as $question) {

    //as a sample there is some data printed for each question.
    print "QuestionType: ". $question->getName()."\n";
    print "QuestionID: ". $question->attributes()->id."\n";
    print "Direction: ".(string) $question->direction."\n";
    print "\n";
    print "Answers: \n";
    foreach($question->answers->answer as $answer){
        print (string)$answer."\n";
    }

    print "\n\n";
}
```

[EDIT]

It prints something like this:

```
QuestionType: trueFalseQuestion
QuestionID: {11AD6662-ACF3-4C2B-A3E6-04311C0DD8DB}
Direction: Le mot de passe de votre compte iNews est indépendant de votre mot de passe radiocanadien géré par ActiveDirectory. 

Answers: 
Vrai 
Faux 


QuestionType: trueFalseQuestion
QuestionID: {F13CF7F1-C830-41AF-A54C-CE78EE383611}
Direction: Le protocole FTP permet de reprendre un transfert de fichier qui a été arrêté, sans recommencer le transfert depuis le début. 

Answers: 
Vrai 
Faux
```

[/EDIT]

Edit2: Added the id to the sample code and sample output

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the revision history of every post is actually stored. Therefore you don't need to indicate that you added something in an edit after posting - anyone can see what did each edit change by clicking on the "edited X secs/mins/hours/days/etc." text.

Comment: I've changed my code to `$xmlData = new SimpleXMLElement($fichierxml);
foreach($xmlData->questions->trueFalseQuestion as $question) {
    $questionid = (string)$question['id'];
    $questionstatus = (string)$question['status'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml_questions ($questionid)
      VALUES ('$questionstatus')";
}` but nothing is inserted in the DB... My columns are labelled as **{11AD6662-ACF3-4C2B-A3E6-04311C0DD8DB}** and **{F13CF7F1-C830-41AF-A54C-CE78EE383611}**. Are the accolades illegal characters?

Comment: I think your database column is named without a "$"-sign. `questionid` So you should try `insert into test_xml_questions (questionid) values …`